# In-App Purchase Server Model, transaction related

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to build an In-App Purchase Server Model. There isnt much helpful sample code for that. So I am trying to write my own.
Here's my questions

1. After the purchase is completed, my app retrieves 'completed transaction' from app store

   - (void) completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
     Then my job is to send this to my server.
     Here, should I send the transaction object itself? or transaction.transactionReceipt string?
     Also how should I send it to my server? ex/ HTTP POST request?? maybe sample code would be helpful
2. Also I read that I should encode with base64 when I send data from apple guide book.
   Is it when I send data from my app to server? or from my server to app store? or both?

please help me out bros~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[verify this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/)  Here there is an verificationcontroller.h and .m you want to add both these files to your project.

Comment: Download and unzip this document’s companion files. (The link is in the top right corner of this page.)
Add the VerificationController.h and VerificationController.m files to your project in Xcode, and add them to the appropriate targets.
Link your project against the Security framework.
Provide a base64 encoder, a base64 decoder, and the action to perform when validation succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *jsonObjectString = [self encodeBase64:(uint8_t*)transaction.transactionReceipt.bytes
                                         length:transaction.transactionReceipt.length];
```

here you want to add base64 for this . And here you want to save the jsonObjectString to your server and you want to provide an sharedsecret here

Comment: Thank you. you are saying that I should encode it using your code. But you did not answer how I should send it to my server? thanks anyway and what do you mean I should add base64? is there a library for that? if there is please tell me where I can get.